# Drop down's OnSelectedIndexChanged event isn't firing when changed

Tags: c#, events, webforms, dropdownbox

I have search a lot, and tried all solutions I could find for this problem, but nothing works.

My OnSelectedIndexChanged event is never fired when selected item in the drop down list is changed.

From View:

```
<asp:DropDownList Name="selectYear" EnableViewState="True" CssClass="select" ID="ddlYear" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

My OnLoad method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    SetText(); //Setting text on labels

    if(IsPostBack)
    {
         return;
    }
    InitDropDown();
    InitGrid();
}
```

I have tried both with and without the post-back-if-statement. None of them is working.

My event metode (this method is never fired, why?):

```
protected void ddlYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnTransactionYearChanged == null) return;
           OnTransactionYearChanged();
}
```

Does anyone know? It's part of a Web Forms applications.

Comment: Comment the `return` statement and try again.

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Where is your breakpoint when you check that event is not called? What is OnTransactionYearChanged ?

Comment: @user2590683 What is your `Page_Load` method?

Comment: OnTransactionYearChanged is some ajax event stuff, but it isn't important for the problem. I can put any kind of code inside e.x. a declaration of a variable, and put the break point on that. Nothing happens. In this case I have the break point on the if-statement.

Comment: @SelvaTS: This is code from one of the user controls which has a lot of other user controls as parents. It's part of a quit big site hierarchy.  So I don't think the Page_load method will cause any problems, as it is used as a base for a lot of sites. Put perhaps the problem could be in one of the other user control parents?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
     return;
}
```

and your dropdownlist is not working properly during postbacks.

Comment: I have tried removing the post back if-statement, but it is not working. Same result.

Comment: I added it based on some suggestions on the same issue on some other blog posts to see if it worked, but it didn't.